# Value of type has no member 'measure' when using XCTest on Xcode 8 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8 beta, when I create an iOS project with Unit Test included, I added the `cocoapods` on my `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift'
pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
pod 'GMStepper'
```

Then I ran the command to init the `cocoapods`:

```
pod install
```

After that I open the `project.xcworkspace` file and then I get these errors:

> Swift Compiler Error
>
> Value of type '[ProjectName]Tests' has no member measure'

[image]

> Ditto Error
>
> Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1

[image]

I just did simple things to create my workspace like I use to do with Xcode 7.3 but this time I can't.

And ideas to solve this?

Comment: "I added the cocoapods" — please describe how you did this.

Comment: @JonReid ok, I edit my question adding my `Podfile`

Comment: I have a same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 No, I didn't. When I update to the latest version of Xcode then I be able to create projects without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of researching I finally solve the errors. The problem was on my `cocoapods` file. I have to specify the target for the main project and for the `Unit Test` project. This is what it looks like now my `cocoapods` file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target "ProjectName" do
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift'
    pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
    pod 'GMStepper'
end

target "ProjectNameTests" do
    pod 'RealmSwift'
    pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.2'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift'
    pod 'SwiftyBeaver'
    pod 'GMStepper'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

Then I ran `pod update` and I cleaned the project and when I builded the project, all the `Unit Tests` errors gone.

Answer (score 4):

I wish I had better knowledge of the issue and could offer a more detailed explanation as to the cause of the errors. I very much dislike "magic" solutions without understanding why they work. That said, magic solutions are better than none at all soooo....

I encountered the problem described above, and came across this SO question while looking for a solution but unfortunately didn't come across a solution. Out of frustration I tried cleaning my project (Product > Clean) which resolved the issue.

I would suspect that something about the cocoapods setup caused some "leftovers" of some sort but it would take someone more experienced than I to delve into the details.

Comment: A (Product -> Clean) plus a (Product -> Build) did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is really late, and you have probably discovered the solution already. I came here with the same question and don't see an answer, so I'm just posting for reference.

[func measure( () -> Void)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase#symbols)

...seems to have disappeared.

```
public func measureBlock(block: () -> Void)
```

...works, though.

Comment: I have a same problem. Did you find the solution?